# Work not showing after bringing it from different computer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.8

I had created an ArcMap document in our GIS lab and completed 80% of the task given; the rest was assigned as homework. Upon returning home I wanted to finish homework. However, now, whenever I open the document, it shows layer names on ‘Table of Content’ but does not show anything on ‘view’. Clicking on ‘full extent’ was no help.

What would be the possible reasons of such error; what would be the remedies? How would I avoid such error in future?

Comment: Unlike in the CAD world, ArcGIS projects do not store data, just references to the path of data. If you didn't bring the data home, you'll need to go back to the lab to zip it up, or start over from where you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the data as map package from the lab. This will help you keep your previously worked data and the .mxd file intact. Later you can open the data in your computer. You can continue your work from where you had stopped. Details about map package (.mpk) can be found here:

https://mapasyst.extension.org/sharing-gis-data-using-an-esri-map-package-mpk/